# What's the pattern of the following JavaScript reduce function?

Tags: javascript, mapreduce

I'm having trouble understanding the following reduce function:

```
function findDeep(arr, obj) {
  return arr.map(item => {
    if (item.name === obj.name) {
      return arr
    } else if (item.children) {
      return findDeep(item.children, obj)
    } else {
      return undefined
    }
  }).reduce((prev, curr) => {
    console.log('prev: ', prev)
    console.log('curr: ', curr)
    return prev || curr
  })
}
```

Applied to this object:

```
const mockApps = {
  name: 'orange',
  children: [{
    name: 'white'
  }, {
    name: 'green',
    children: [{
      name: 'yellow',
      children: [{
        name: 'red'
      }, {
        name: 'white'
      }]
    }, {
      name: 'green',
      children: [{
        name: 'purple'
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'gray'
  }]
}

const activeApp = {
  name: 'purple',
  color: 'purple',
  path: 'writer'
}

findDeep(mockApps.children, activeApp)
```

I thought the pattern would be like the example at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
  return previousValue + currentValue;
});
```

[image]

But to my surprise what I theorized was different from the output:

[image]

I thought the `previousValue` would be the `returnValue` of the previous iteration, but as you can see in the console, the third `prev` is undefined even if the `currentValue` of the previous iteration is not.

What's the correct pattern of this `reduce` function?

Here's the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/alexcheninfo/pen/QNrGRj).

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: The *findDeep* function requires an array and object, you've shown the object, what does the array look like?

Comment: @RobG I updated the question.

Comment: *activeApp* is another Object, the *arr* parameter **must** be an Array (or some other object with a *map* method that returns an Array or an object with a *reduce* method).

Comment: @RobG  I'm passing `mockApps.children` to `arr`. `mockApps.children` is an array.

Comment: Did any of the answers answer your question. Could you mark the one that did, or leave a comment?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are assuming the console output belongs to one run of `reduce`, but this is not true.

The function `findDeep` calls itself recursively, so you'll get output from distinct calls to `reduce`.

I suggest you modify the code as follows to also see in the console when `findDeep` is being called and exited:

```
function findDeep(arr, obj) {
  console.log('Entering findDeep');
  var res = arr.map(item => {
    if (item.name === obj.name) {
      return arr
    } else if (item.children) {
      return findDeep(item.children, obj)
    } else {
      return undefined
    }
  }).reduce((prev, curr) => {
    console.log('prev: ' + JSON.stringify(prev));
    console.log('curr: ' + JSON.stringify(curr));
    console.log('return: ' + JSON.stringify(prev || curr));
    return prev || curr;
  });
  console.log('Exiting from findDeep');
  return res;
}
```

This should bring light to the issue. Here is a snippet that writes the log to the browser:

```js
console = { log: function(msg) {
  document.write(msg + '<br>');
}}

function findDeep(arr, obj) {
  console.log('Entering findDeep');
  var res = arr.map(item => {
    if (item.name === obj.name) {
      return arr
    } else if (item.children) {
      return findDeep(item.children, obj)
    } else {
      return undefined
    }
  }).reduce((prev, curr) => {
    console.log('prev: ' + JSON.stringify(prev));
    console.log('curr: ' + JSON.stringify(curr));
    console.log('return: ' + JSON.stringify(prev || curr));
    return prev || curr;
  });
  console.log('Exiting from findDeep');
  return res;
}

const mockApps = {
  name: 'orange',
  children: [{
    name: 'white'
  }, {
    name: 'green',
    children: [{
      name: 'yellow',
      children: [{
        name: 'red'
      }, {
        name: 'white'
      }]
    }, {
      name: 'green',
      children: [{
        name: 'purple'
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'gray'
  }]
}

const activeApp = {
  name: 'purple',
  color: 'purple',
  path: 'writer'
}

findDeep(mockApps.children, activeApp)
```

As you can see, where previously it seemed the value of `prev` did not correspond to the return value of the previous iteration, it now becomes clear that these two iterations belong to a different call of `reduce`, so it acts just like you expect.

Comment: I edited the code to make it ES5 compliant, I would have put a comment in the edit but clicked on *save* instead of *Run code snippet*. :-/

Comment: But why? The OP uses ES6, there is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Oh, `JSON.stringify(undefined)` returns the value `undefined` because the result is literally, not defined so it returns `undefined`. Same as `JSON.stringify(function(){})`. ;-)

Comment: Yes, I know. But your deleted comment said it gave null. Never mind.

Comment: Because many others are running browsers that don't yet do ECMAScript 2015 and the answer should suit everyone.

Comment: In that case I feel a comment to the OP would be more appropriate. I prefer my answer to fit with the language chosen by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the code through, the first value passed to *map* (level 0) is:

```
{name: 'white'}
```

It doesn't have a name of purple, or any children so the result array is now:

```
[undefined]
```

The next item is:

```
{name: 'green',
 children: [{
   name: 'yellow',
   children: [{
     name: 'red'
     }, {
     name: 'white'
     }]
   }, {
     name: 'green',
     children: [{
       name: 'purple'
     }]
   }]
}
```

It has a *children* property so its value is passed to a recursive call to *findDeep* (level 1), which is:

```
 [{
   name: 'yellow',
   children: [{
     name: 'red'
     }, {
     name: 'white'
     }]
   }, {
     name: 'green',
     children: [{
       name: 'purple'
     }]
 }]
```

The first item passed to *map*, and again *findDeep* is called recursively (level 2) with:

```
   [{name: 'red'},
    {name: 'white'}]
   }, {
     name: 'green',
     children: [{
       name: 'purple'
     }]
```

the first item has no *name* of purple or children, so this level map array is now:

```
[undefined]
```

Same for the next item, so now it's:

```
[undefined, undefined]
```

The next has a name 'purple', so it's added to the array:

```
[undefined, undefined,{name:'purple'}]
```

That is run through *reduce*, which is called with no accumulator so the first two values are passed as *prev* and *cur*. Since *prev* is falsey, the value of *curr* is returned as the accumulator so on the next call the values are *undefined* and `{name:'purple'}`, so that's returned to the level 1 *map* and it's array is now:

```
[{name:'purple'}]
```

There are no more members in this level, so that is passed to reduced. Since it's the only member in the array and there's no accumulator passed in, it's simply returned, so the level 1 result is:

```
[{name:'purple'}]
```

The last member at level 0 also returns undefined, so the final level 0 array is:

```
[{name:'purple'}, undefined]
```

Which is passed to reduce, with the two values being *prev* and *curr* respectively. Since *prev* the object isn't falsey, it's returned and the final result is:

```
[{name:'purple'}]
```

Note that if you use *JSON.stringify* to look at objects and arrays, *undefined* is changed to "null".